# Prioritising duplicates from csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv which contains a number of rows which have some duplicates of the `'gmc_number'` . For some there are 2 entries with the same gmc_number, for others there are more than 2.

For each set of duplicates I  would like to assign the rows into either the `delete` category or `keep` category based upon a set of criteria which are as follows:

**1. Login_dt:**

If only row has a non null login_dt then mark this to `keep` and the rest to `delete`

If more than one row have non-null `login_dt` then continue on to step 2 with these rows and mark any rows with null `login_dt` as `delete`.

If all rows have null `login_dt` then do not mark any and continue on to step 2 with these rows.

**2. Hash**

If only row has a non null `hash` then mark this to `keep` and the rest to `delete`

If more than one row have non-null `hash` then continue on to step 3 with these values and mark any rows with null `hash` as `delete`.

If all rows have null `hash` then do not mark any and continue on to step 3 with these rows.

**3. Register_dt**

Now we want to order by the most recent `register_dt`. Mark the row with the most recent `register_dt` as `keep` and the rest as `delete`.

---

I assume python would be a good way of doing this. But I can't figure out how I would perform this upon the sets of duplicates. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In step 1, what if all rows have a null `login_df`? Same for step 2 with `hash` and potentially step 3 with `register_dt` (if that can also be null).

Comment: sorry I missed that out. We should continue to the next step with all the rows

Comment: Python is a good way of doing this, but if you're starting from a position of not knowing how to program at all, then writing your first program will be daunting. You'll need to look stuff up like "python how read from csv," "python how iterate through rows," and so on. Or if you are starting from a position of having done some scripting before, then what have you tried?

Comment: Some advice as you're experimenting: don't modify your source file. Write a script that reads your source file, and creates a `"processed-{yourfilename.csv}"`. That way, you're free to make mistakes.

Comment: @ben I have some basic knowledge of PHP, SQL, C and started a little bit of python but have forgotten most of it. Would prefer to try to solve this myself and learn in the process rather than get somebody else to do it.